# How do I put 2D array to use?

Tags: vba

I've used i and j array to hold values, is there a way to combine both by using multidimension array or condense another way?

```
Dim iArray 
Dim jArray
With wks.Range("B2:B" & p)
    iArray = .Value
End With 
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
.comparemode = 2
    For Each item In iArray
        If Not .exists(item) Then
        .Add item, Nothing
        End If
    Next
        If .Count Then
            Me.Search1.List = Application.Transpose(.keys)
        End If
End With

With wks.Range("c2:c" & p)
    jArray = .Value
End With 
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
.comparemode = 1
    For Each item In jArray
        If Not .exists(item) Then
        .Add item, Nothing
        End If
    Next
        If .Count Then
            Me.Search2.List = Application.Transpose(.keys)
        End If
End With
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way, using multidimensional array. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2de1t93(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should consider extracting that functionality to a standalone sub which you can cell with parameters:

```
Sub ListUniquesFromRange(rng As Range, lst As Object)
    Dim iArray, v
    If rng.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "single-column range only!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    iArray = rng.Value
    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        .comparemode = 2
        For Each v In iArray
            If Not .exists(v) Then .Add v, Nothing
        Next
        If .Count Then
            lst.List = Application.Transpose(.keys)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Then you can do this:

```
ListUniquesFromRange wks.Range("B2:B" & p), Me.Search1
ListUniquesFromRange wks.Range("C2:C" & p), Me.Search2
```